# Regex match all new lines that does not come before a closing tag

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match all new lines that does not come before a closing html tag.

`word word word` --------- Should match 
 
`word word word </p>`
`word word word` --------- Should match

** I do understand that regex is **not reliable** tool, but for my case it more than enough. And simple regex will do the work, I'm just not good at them.

`(?<![>])[\n]` - Work in Chrome, but no in Firefox (SyntaxError: invalid regexp group)

Comment: Are you getting this text directly from HTML?

Comment: Because if you are, you could just use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent ...

Comment: *"...new lines that does not come before a closing html tag"*: if anything, your regex is testing for newlines that do not come *after* a tag.

Comment: Firefox does not support look-behind yet.

Comment: @kemicofa yes, it's from input field. I do some manipulation and then   inputData.replace(/(?<![>])[\n]/g, '<br>')

Comment: I think you can use the following regex: `\b\n`. You can see a working example [here (regex101)](https://regex101.com/r/AEKqHR/1)

Comment: The trick is that you can match the word boundaries without consuming characters, this only would work for alphanumeric characters at the end of the line

Comment: @RodrigoFerreira But this does not match something like `word.\n` unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `inputData.replace(/([^>])[\n]/g, '$1<br>')` or workarounds suggested in ["Manually Implementing Lookbehind"](http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch19.html#regexp-look-behind).